How to Achieve Animated Transitions Between Screens in Jetpack Compose?
I’m trying to create a navigation flow in my Jetpack Compose app that features smooth animated transitions between screens, similar to the effect seen in videos. Currently, when I navigate from the StartScreen to the LoginScreen, the StartScreen overlays the LoginScreen, which doesn't create the desired effect.
@Composable
fun MyAppNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier, authViewModel: AuthViewModel
) {

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "start") {
        composable(route = "start",
            enterTransition = {
                slideInHorizontally(
                    initialOffsetX = { -500 }, // small slide 300px
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000,
                        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing // interpolator
                    )
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutHorizontally(
                    targetOffsetX = { -500 },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000,
                        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                    )
                )
            }) {
            StartPage(
                modifier = modifier,
                navController = navController,
                authViewModel = authViewModel
            )
        }

        composable(route = "login",
            enterTransition = {
                slideInHorizontally(
                    initialOffsetX = { it }, // it == fullWidth
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000,
                        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                    )
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutHorizontally(
                    targetOffsetX = { it },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000,
                        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                    )
                )
            }

        ) {
                LoginPage(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    navController = navController,
                    authViewModel = authViewModel
                )
        }

        composable("signup") {
            SignupPage(
                modifier = modifier,
                navController = navController,
                authViewModel = authViewModel
            )
        }

        composable("home") {
            HomePage(
                modifier = modifier,
                navController = navController,
                authViewModel = authViewModel
            )
        }


    }
}

This is what i want to achieve.

i tried to change numbers of initialoffset but weren't able to achieve it.

Instead of adding an enter/exit transition to the composable, try adding the transitions to the NavHost directly instead and remove them from the composables. Another advantage of this will is that you only need to define these transition effects once and it will apply to everything.
My code looks something like this:
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScope
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween

const val SCREEN_TRANSITION_MILLIS = 500

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Screen.HomeTab.route,
    enterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(
        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(
            SCREEN_TRANSITION_MILLIS
        )
    ) },
    exitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(
        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(
            SCREEN_TRANSITION_MILLIS
        )
    ) },
    popEnterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(
        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(
            SCREEN_TRANSITION_MILLIS
        )
    ) },
    popExitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(
        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(
            SCREEN_TRANSITION_MILLIS
        )
    ) }
) {
    composable(Screen.HomeTab.route) {
        HomeView(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
    composable(Screen.SomeListView.route) {
        SomeListView(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
    // Remaining composables....
}


Thanks for your solution it's really helpful, can you help me achieve same animation as horizonalPager @omz1990

similar to when i go to next page and return to prev one

@FatimaJamal to achieve the exact navigation style as iOS in the video you posted, you won't be able to get it with a simple animation effect. You would need to wrap each composable in a container composable e.g. SwipeGestureHandler. Pass the navController, offsetX, onSwipeBack, and onSwipeReset to SwipeGestureHandler. Inside SwipeGestureHandler, use pointerInput to detect horizontal swipe gestures. Set offsetX for the swipe distance. Call navController.popBackStack() in onSwipeBack when swipe exceeds 300px.

@FatimaJamal If your use-case is limited like the video, the easier path might be to add your views to a HorizontalPager and conditionally enable/disable swiping to mimic navigation. Having said that, Android and iOS have separate navigation patterns provided out of the box, my suggestion would be to stick with those as opposed to replicating iOS on Android. However, if its a hard client requirement, then my previous comment would be the way to go for a scalable solution.

Thanks for your suggest to stick with the resources available. I wanted to learn if that is possible, but i'm currently using HorizontalPager itself cuz it's easier in it's implementation.
